# generate labels for arrows in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

For my thesis I want to incorporate some Tikz images which make rather heavy use of labeled arrows. I was wondering if there is an efficient way of generating these, rather than defining them one-by-one. Unfortunately, I am not that familiar with the `foreach` command, which I guess would come in handy here. One example image is shown below:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,fill=gray}]
            \node (n1) at (-2,10) {1};
            \node (n2) at (0,10) {2};
            \node (n3) at (2,10) {3};
            \node (n4) at (1,8) {4};
            \node (n5) at (-1,8) {5};
            \node (BS) at (3,7) {6};

            \foreach \from/\to in {n1/n2,n2/n1,n2/n3,n3/n2,n3/n4,n4/n3,n4/n5,n5/n4,n1/n5,n5/n1,n2/n5,n5/n2,n4/BS,BS/n4}
            \draw[->, bend right=22.5] (\from) to (\to);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image to which the labels need to be added]

What I now want to do is add labels `$T_{ij}$` to each arrow, where `$i$` is the node of origin and `$j$` is the destination node for the arrow. So, for example for the arrows between nodes 1 and 2 this would be T_12 and T_21.

Answer (score 4):

With a bit of fiddling I managed to get to this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (1) at (-4,6) {1};
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (2) at (0,6) {2};
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (3) at (4,6) {3};
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (4) at (2,2) {4};
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (5) at (-2,2) {5};
        \node[circle,fill=gray] (6) at (6,0) {BS};

        \foreach \from/\to in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,4/6,5/2,5/1}
        {\draw[->, bend right=22.5] (\from) to node[fill=white] {$T_{\from \to}$} (\to);
            \draw[->, bend right=22.5] (\to) to node[fill=white] {$T_{\to \from}$} (\from);
        }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Picture with labels now added]

Which pretty much gives the result I was looking for. However, I had to rename my nodes to do this or the labeling command would not have worked, as it would have given the wrong indices to the labels.

Comment: This is basically what I was working on for a solution; however, I was adding conditional code to handle nodes containing strings, such as `BS`. What is the significance of the arrows to and from BS having `6` in their labels?

Comment: My apologies, I had not thought that part through. The thesis is on robotic networks. Node 6 happens to be a fixed base station, so that is why I initally labeled it `BS`. However, for elegance it is nice to have the accompanying transmission rate represented as `$T_{46}$` rather than `$T_{4BS}$`, as the latter doesn't really make sense mathematically. I'll update the question/answer accordingly to avoid further confusion, thank you for pointing it out!